# AngularJS google places autocomplete clear field

Tags: angularjs, google-places-api

Im using the google places autocomplete with the following directive. The directive works fine, but when I clear the autocomplete field, the place_changed event does not fire.  What can I do in order to ensure that it fires and clears the field when the user deletes the value in the autocomplete box?

```
app.directive('googleplace', function() {
  return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope:{place : '='},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
          var options = {
              types: []
          };
          scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

          google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {

              scope.place = scope.gPlace.getPlace();

              scope.$apply(function() {
                  model.$setViewValue(element.val());
              });

          });
      }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The google maps documentation says about "Getting Place Information" (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places):

"When a user selects a Place from the predictions attached to the text field, the service fires a place_changed event. The Places service also returns a PlaceResult object, which can be accessed by calling getPlace() on the Autocomplete object."

So I understood that if the user clear the input box, so any prediction is returned, because it is blank, that event won't be called.

If you would like to read values from the DOM, then you should implement a function and add it to the $parsers array of `ngModelController` variable, in your case, named `model`